# WSO2 IS 5.0.0 sso user's claims retrieval error

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, claims, wso2-identity-server

I'm using SAML 2.0 authentication on WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and I have configured 3 service providers to work with. I have also set up custom user store for my user accounts and using domain related authentication. Everytime I try to log in using domain account (domain/user) my custom user store doAuthenticate is properly called.

What is confusing is that if I configure different sets of claims for each provider(sp1=claim1, claim2; sp2=claim1, claim3; sp3=claim5), I start to get the ones from the first provider where user has logged in (for instance, if the first sp where user logs in is sp1, all SAMLResponses from that time from all providers contains claim1, claim2). So that means all providers receives claim set from the first provider.

Which is wrong and I feel this to be a bug. A serious bug. Can anyone guide me where should I start looking for resolving this?

Recently I have patched my authorization module with this patch:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2691

Thank you in advance,

Josef

Comment: Did you try with the service pack available for WSO2 Identity server http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/

Comment: Sorry Ishara, not yet. Because I have made some changes to the authentication endpoint and I cannot find sources for this service pack, I won't risk next problem ... which could eventually occur if I fix all files around but authentication endpoint.

Comment: Ahoj Josef, the service pack is really critical, fixes a lot of 'not working' issues..